# Start the wsl terminal to the same path as of VSCode project folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I work on various projects located in different directories. So I can't be specific to CWD settings in
VSCode using

> `"terminal.integrated.cwd": ""`

Whenever I open a folder in VSCode with remote-wsl I want my terminal to be also open at the same location as of folder. I have trouble figuring it how to achieve this actually or have I missed something in VSCode settings.

Comment: When you have `""`, the cwd will be project root, is that what you want ?

Comment: No, that root will be also a default directory, that's not what I want @Philippe

Comment: I think this feature is currently in progress. Hoping to have this soon in my armoury